# Can't kill mono process (Mono + NLog)

Tags: mono, nlog

I've got a process running in mono on Ubuntu 12 server.  Occasionally when attempting to stop the process, it won't exit completely.  kill pid doesn't kill the process, however kill -9 pid will successfully kill the process.

If I issue a kill -QUIT pid, I get the following:

> "unnamed thread" tid=0x0xb753b700 this=0x0x56f18 thread handle 0x403 state : waiting on 0x400 : Event  owns ()

I'm assuming one of my threads isn't exiting properly, Any suggestions on where to start looking for the problem?

Comment: are you using NLog by any chance?

Comment: I am.  I followed the instructions here http://nlog-project.org/2011/10/30/using-nlog-with-mono.html but still have intermittent problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a Mono known issue, which a user fixed in a pull request which was merged, and the first version to include the fix is Mono 3.0.8:

https://github.com/mono/mono/pull/505

Comment: So even by setting the LogManager.Configuration to null as detailed in the NLog site, I would still experience this problem?

Comment: If you use Mono without the patch in the pull-request applied, yes

Comment: I'm hesitant to blame it on the NLog issue.  I replaced the NLog 2.0 dll with the 1.0 refresh dll and am experiencing the same issue.  From what I understand, NLog is only to blame when using 2.0.

Comment: try shay's patch and check if it fixes your issue, what can I say?